# I want to check string using regex | not nested, stuck together and must have content

Tags: regex

I have some strings.

1. [ABC]
2. [ABC][DEF]
3. [ABC][def][GH][I] and etc.

and there are rules.

1. Do not nested.

- [ABC] : OK
- [A[BC]] : NO

2. Not allowed any character between each brackets. (includes white spaces)

- [ABC][DE] : OK
- [AB] [C] : NO
- [AB]c[DEF] : NO

3. String must start with "[" and end with "]"
4. Bracket content can have word and number only. not empty or blank.

Here is my works. But it seems not good. 
`^\[\w.*(\w\]\[\w).*\w\]$` 
https://regex101.com/r/EQzulB/1

How do I check if this string is valid or invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^\[\w.*(\w\]\[\w).*\w\]$` regex matches the start of string (`^`), then `[`, a word char, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, then a word char, `][` and a word char captured into Group 1, then again any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and a word char followed by a `]` char at the end of string (`$`).  So, `[ABC]` and `[A[BC]]` can't match, there is no `w][w` in it.

You can use

```php
^(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+])+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dyMbF6/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
  - `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.

If you allow underscores, too, inside the square brackets, use `\w`:

```php
^(?:\[\w+])+$
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your kindness. It's exactly what I want to know.